# How to combine databases with other some of which i do not have permission to edit in pgadmin 4

Tags: sql, pgadmin-4

I apologize for possible dumbness/ incompentence before hand.
general aim: I have a database (mimiciii) which i do not have permission to do a lot of things.
(nb i tried to snapshot what access do i have but I cannot even see what permission, which i tried
\l,
SELECT grantee, privilege_type
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
WHERE table_name='mytable',
\du etc)
but i digress and come back to the main topic.
Simply, I have a another CSV file which i need to combine with the database for analysis.
but I do not have permission to edit said database

methods tried:
I tried making a temporary table--> and then copy the contents of the CSV
(yes i am aware that i will then have to do this for every query, which is very dumb, and is the one of the things that my dumb brain though of)
tried the COPY  in SQL--> did not have permission-->
tried the  \COPY COVID FROM 'address of file' DELIMITER ',' CSV--> "address of file": Permission denied--> went to see the hoster of my progressadmin 4 (Nb, i am using a virtual desktop, i dont know whether it will affect things) --> enabled user for the file--> restarted--> still didnt work

I observed that there was other schema parallel to the part which I did not have access to, and i was able to create permanent tables on it. Quick googling told me that i could fuse table and do stuff across schemas, but I seem to be not be able to access it by SQL since everytime i typed schema_name.table (for every table in said schema) it tells me it does not exist, despite literally existing and repeated proofreading. I couldnt find any more information of this online.

I might be overthinking by a lot, since this is for my coursework and it shouldnt be this hard. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Assuming that you want to do this analysis in a database then you need to have access to a database where you have the necessary privileges. This is not something anyone else can help you with - either create your own database and import your data into it out ask the owner of an existing database to grant you the necessary permissions

Comment: @NickW what if i dont necessarily need to do this analysis in this database? So would the solution be importing both the database and the csv file that i have to a new server so that I could do the analysis with the combined dataset at the same time?

Comment: You would need to import the data into whatever tool/platform you are going to do the analysis in. As this answer is so self-evident I’m wondering if we are talking past each other?

Comment: my knowledge on Pgadmin is shakey at best. But i do think ill be able to manage that. Ill come back when I'll need more help. THANKS A LOT!